# Iterate through a list with a fixed range

Tags: python, loops

I am just starting out with Python for my research and I am stuck at a problem which I believe is very generic but somehow I am not able to do it. I have a list of tweets and want to run Botometer lite for checking Bot scores.

Botometer has a rate limit of 200 calls a day where each call can have a maximum of 100 tweets.

Keeping this in mind, I wish to kind of automate the process where in each iteration, Botometerlite takes 100 accounts from the list and shows the botscore (preferably saves it to a csv) and repeats this iteration for max 200 times.

I am doing it manually which feels a bit off.

```py
accounts = tweets['username'].tolist()

accounts1 =  accounts[27900:28000]    #100 accounts

print(accounts1)

rapidapi_key = "xxxxxxx"
twitter_app_auth = {
    'consumer_key': 'xxxxx',
    'consumer_secret': 'xxxxxx',
    'access_token': 'xxxx',
    'access_token_secret': 'xxxx',
  }
blt_twitter = botometer.BotometerLite(rapidapi_key=rapidapi_key, **twitter_app_auth)

blt_scores = blt_twitter.check_accounts_from_screen_names(accounts1)

print(blt_scores)
```

I am sure it needs some kind of a loop. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Sorry if it is a trivial query.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(200):
    accounts1 = accounts[100 * i + offset:100 * (i + 1) + offset]
    bot_function(accounts1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code works fine however, I would like to know how can I use the loop if I wish to start for instance, from the index 28,000 as I already have the output for 0:28000. I am asking for this because I can check up to 20,000 accounts per day and would prefer to build over it every other day. I hope you are able to understand my question.

Comment: @RR31 Within the list slicing, you can just add an offset of your completed items (28,000). I edited the answer.